# PHP MongoDB aggregation returns empty

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to implement an average calculation over a mongo dataset using `MongoCollection()::aggregate()`, but the functions returns a Cursor object and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This a sample of the dataset content:

```
{ word : "word", time : 1234, result  : "pass" }
```

This pipeline query works in the mongo console:

```
{"$group" : 
   {"_id" : "$result", 
    "meanTime" : {"$avg" :"$time"}
   }
}
```

This is my code:

```
    public function  getTimes($fields = array('correct','wrong','pass')){


    $group = ['$group'=> ["_id" => '$result', "meanTime" => ['$avg' =>'$time']]];

    $agg = $this->collection->aggregate(
                    [$group]
                    );
    return $agg;

}
/*
//This is the var_dump on $agg
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#82 (2) {
["cursor"]=>
array(17) {
["stamp"]=>
int(0)
["is_command"]=>
bool(false)
["sent"]=>
bool(true)
["done"]=>
bool(false)
["end_of_event"]=>
bool(false)
["in_exhaust"]=>
bool(false)
["has_fields"]=>
bool(false)
["query"]=>
object(stdClass)#76 (0) {
}
["fields"]=>
    object(stdClass)#74 (0) {
    }
    ["read_preference"]=>
    array(2) {
    ["mode"]=>
      int(1)
      ["tags"]=>
      array(0) {
    }
    }
    ["flags"]=>
    int(0)
    ["skip"]=>
    int(0)
    ["limit"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["batch_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["ns"]=>
    string(23) "circular.intesavincente"
["current_doc"]=>
    object(stdClass)#83 (2) {
    ["_id"]=>
      string(4) "pass"
["meanTime"]=>
      float(338)
    }
  }
  ["server_id"]=>
  int(1)
}

//This is the json_encode output
{}

*/
```

I have tried to write the pipeline array with both `array()` construct and simplified `[]`, but the result is unchanged. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the MongoDB driver and [mongo-php-library](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) I guess. If so the result is such as should be. You could notice [meanTime] field in the result. You just need apply [toArray()](http://php.net/manual/ru/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) method to the resulting MongoDB\Driver\Cursor.
Something like this (based on your initial code):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Timer
{
    public $collection;

    public function getTimes()
    {
        $group = [
            '$group' => [
                "_id"      => '$result',
                "meanTime" => [
                    '$avg' => '$time',
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $this->collection->aggregate([$group]);
    }
}

$timer = new Timer;
$m = new MongoDB\Client();
$db = $m->test;
$timer->collection = $db->so;
$cursor = $timer->getTimes();
$result = $cursor->toArray();
echo var_export($result[0]->bsonSerialize(), false);

//
// stdClass::__set_state(array(
// '_id' => 'pass',
// 'meanTime' => 1234,
//))
```

You can also see the library documentation to using various methods properly.

You could use the mongo.so extension to see more clear result but this extension is deprecated now.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that the object returned was a cursor instead of an array. Funny thing is I correctly converted to array a similar object a couple lines above that function. I guess Ballmer's peak is real